# Graph path-finding algorithm variant

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

I am looking for an algorithm that takes an undirected graph as input and finds a subset of vertices such that the subgraph induced by those vertices forms a connected acyclic tree.

For instance, in the following figure the 'X' nodes would create a valid solution, but including any of the 'O' nodes would make it invalid.

```
    O
   /|
O-X-X-X
 \ /
  X-X
```

The usefulness of the solution to me is proportionate to the size of the subset. Although I don't need the entire maximal subset, a close approximation would be very helpful.

I've tried the obvious algorithm of starting with a random node and adding adjacent vertices if they don't induce a cycle. However, I have the feeling that this produces very suboptimal trees.

I should mention that my particular application involves graphs of ~100 nodes and ~1000 edges. This is small enough that brute-force backtracking algorithms might be feasible if well implemented (e.g. using [Dancing Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links),  but I haven't tried this out.

Comment: Are you looking for a subset large as possible?

Comment: As I explained, the large the subset the better, but it doesn't need to be provably the largest. Approximations and heuristics are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is <strike>called</strike> very similar to [Feedback Vertex Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set), and unfortunately it's NP-hard.  According to the Wikipedia page, the best known approximation algorithm has an [approximation ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm#Performance_guarantees) of 2: [Becker, Ann; Geiger, Dan (1996), "Optimization of Pearl's method of conditioning and greedy-like approximation algorithms for the vertex feedback set problem."](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2F0004-3702%2895%2900004-6).

### NP-hardness proof for "Connected Feedback Vertex Set"

I neglected the condition that the resulting graph needs to be connected, which is not the case for Feedback Vertex Set (FVS).  Below I'll show that your problem, which I'll call Connected Feedback Vertex Set (CVFS), is nevertheless NP-hard.

Given an instance (G = (V, E), k) of FVS, we need to construct an instance (G' = (V', E'), k') of CFVS with the property that (G, k) is a YES-instance of FVS if and only if (G', k') is a YES-instance of CFVS.  Informally this G' will look like a "stack of copies" of G, with a few extra vertices and edges.  Let's do this as follows:

For each vertex v_i in V, create a path (**not** a clique, as I originally said in the comments...) of |V| vertices v'_i_j in V', 1 <= j <= |V|.  These are the "meat vertices".  (You can think of vertex v'_i_j being in "layer" j.)  The vertices v'_i_1, v'_i_2, ..., v'_i_|V| are the "strand" of meat corresponding to vertex v_i in G (yes, terrible name...).

For each edge (v_i, v_j) in E, create all |V| corresponding "parallel" edges between the corresponding vertices in G' -- that is, create the edges (v'_i_1, v'_j_1), (v'_i_2, v'_j_2), ..., (v'_i_|V|, v'_j_|V|).  (These edges all connect vertices that are in the same layer.)

For each vertex v_i in V, also create an additional "skeleton vertex" u'_i in V'.  Make this u'_i adjacent to v'_i_1.

Add another vertex r to V', and make it adjacent to every skeleton vertex u'_i.

Finally, set k' = |V|*k + |V| - 1.

First I'll show that if the FVS instance (G, k) is a YES-instance, then (G', k') is a YES-instance of your problem.  Let X be any solution (i.e., set of deleted vertices) to the FVS instance (G, k) that leaves at least 1 vertex of G undeleted (such a solution must exist, since a 1-vertex graph contains no cycle); then we can construct a solution X' to the instance of your problem as follows:

1. For each vertex v_i deleted in the FVS solution X, we can delete the corresponding path v_i_1, ..., v_i_|V| from G' at a total cost of at most |V|*k (deleting each path costs |V| vertex deletions, and at most k vertices were deleted from G by X).  This guarantees that there will be no cycle consisting only of meat vertices in G'-X' (if there were, this would contradict the feasibility of the FVS solution X to (G, k)).
2. For each connected component in the FVS solution X, we can delete all but 1 of the corresponding skeleton vertices in G'.  What we are left with in G' is a stack of |V| copies of the FVS solution G-X, plus a single skeleton vertex per component of that solution, plus the root vertex r.  Since we only have a single path to r from each connected component (via a single skeleton vertex per component), there can be no cycle in G'.  Since G-X contains at least 1 connected component, this can involve at most |V|-1 deletions, so at most |V|*k + |V| - 1 deletions were needed overall, so the answer to the constructed CFVS instance (G', k') is YES.

Secondly I'll show that if the constructed instance (G', k') of your problem is a YES-instance, then the original instance (G, k) of FVS is a YES-instance.

Let X' be any solution (i.e., set of deleted vertices) to the constructed instance (G', k') of CFVS.  Consider the subgraph induced by each layer of meat vertices in G'-X': there are |V| such layers.  In general, different layers could contain different numbers of deletions.  Choose any layer j that contains a minimum number of deletions; since G'-X' is cycle-free, so is every induced subgraph, including in particular layer j.  The number of deletions in layer j is at most k'/|V|, since otherwise (by the minimal choice of j) there would be strictly more than k' deletions overall, a contradiction.  But any integer <= k'/|V| must be <= RoundDown((|V|*k + |V| - 1) / |V|) = k, and layer j is just a copy of the original FVS problem (G, k), so it is possible to destroy every cycle in layer j -- and thus in the original FVS instance (G, k) -- with at most k deletions.  This implies that (G, k) is a YES-instance of FVS.

(G, k) being a YES-instance of FVS implies (G', k') being a YES-instance of CFVS, and vice versa, so (G, k) being a NO-instance of FVS implies (G', k') being a NO-instance of CFVS, so the problems instances are equivalent.  Clearly (G', k') can be constructed in polynomial time from (G, k), so it follows that CVFS is NP-hard.  It's also clearly NP-complete, since a solution to a YES-instance can be checked for correctness (that is, cycle-freeness and connectedness) in O(|V|+|E|) time with a single DFS.

Comment: Awesome, knowing the name of a problem makes it much easier to find solutions. I do have a slight additional constraint, which is that I would like a single connected tree rather than a forest.

Comment: I see.  I'm pretty sure this is still NP-hard; I'll add a proof sketch if I get the time to think it through.  (The basic idea would be to take any FVS instance, blow up each vertex to a clique of about n vertices, then add a light "skeleton" of vertices that connects all these cliques together, and argue that any solution to the FVS instance corresponds to a solution of your problem that leaves the skeleton intact.)

Comment: I'd be interested in that proof sketch. My solution would necessarily be a smaller (or equal) subset than the FVS forest, but I think you could come up with examples where my optimal tree and the FVS forest share relatively few nodes. However I haven't read Becker yet so it's possible I'm misunderstanding your idea.

Comment: If it's NP-hard, maybe I should just try for an exponential algorithm and hope my instances are small enough for it to be practical.

Comment: @Quantum7: I've now added a hardness proof for your *actual* problem ;-)  It turned out that I needed to use paths instead of cliques.

Comment: Nice proof! With this I will stop searching for something more efficient than backtracking.

Comment: Thanks :)  You should definitely first of all look for any bridges (edges whose deletion splits a connected component into 2 connected components) and delete them, since no cycle can use such an edge -- that means you can solve both of the resulting CCs independently.  If you're lucky this might end up with many small instances.

Answer (score 0):

This sound like [finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) the [maximum spanning tree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumSpanningTree.html) and then taking a subset using the structure of it should probably help.

If not, try this:

1. Find the node with least amount of edges.
2. If by adding it to the subset you still have a tree, mark it as belonging to the subset and "erase" all its edges from the graph.
3. Repeat step 1 until all nodes not in the subset can't be added.

Hope this helps

Comment: The maximal spanning tree doesn't work since a spanning tree can include many pairs of nodes that contained an edge in the original graph. As to your other procedure, applying it literally would result in a single-vertex subset in the first step. Trying to guess what you mean, I think you were suggesting a heuristic where new nodes are added to the tree if they don't violate the criteria. This is more-or-less what I'm trying now (with poor results), although I haven't tried the heuristic of ordering nodes by the number of edges.